# Netbox in docker LDAP authentication

Tags: active-directory, ldap, netbox

does anybody know a manual or tutorial in the web how I can configure LDAP in netbox which is installed in a docker environment.

Kind regards

I searched for docs in the Internet watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOs8xZyJ6EY
But its for non docker installations